# American Buying AC Milan Tickets

Tags: football

I'm traveling to Milan in April and noticed that AC Milan is playing Carpi during the time I am there. The official AC Milan website does not have any tickets available (http://tickets.acmilan.com/en/tickets_purchase) so it looks like I will likely have to go to the secondary market. I see that seatwave.com is a subsidiary of Ticketmaster, is that my best bet?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about actually competing in a sport.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I agree this is off-topic, but not because it's not about competing in a sport. [Fandom](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/a/397) is important in [sports](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and attending games is part of that. I think "[shopping recommendation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)" wrt where to buy tickets is closer to the reason why this question is off topic.

Comment: This question is off topic because this is a [shopping recommendation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) with respect to where to purchase tickets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tickets are not available because it is too early for the buy.
You can try to buy them few days before or that day at the stadium.

I am almost sure that Milan-Carpi will not sign the sold out

Comment: Thanks Ale -- didn't realize that tickets don't go on sale until just before the match.  Good to know!